# Persisting a Checkbox's State and Toggling a Core Data BOOL

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a checkbox class that I want to toggle a boolean core data attribute from `NO` to `YES`. Drawing the actual checkbox and getting it to toggle isn't the issue, but persisting its state is. The checkbox is in the second view controller in my stack (`RVC` <--> `ItemsVC` (checkboxes are here) <--> `ItemDetailVC`). If I toggle the checkbox and then navigate either way, the state returns to unchecked.

I've tried a few ways to a) make the checkbox state persist and to b) make the state of the checkbox change the state of my boolean attribute from `NO` to `YES`.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    // Initialization code

    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self addTarget:self action: @selector(checkboxTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
return self;
}

- (IBAction) checkboxTapped {
if (self.isChecked == NO) {
    self.isChecked = YES;
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.selectedItem.inCart = isChecked;
} else {
    self.isChecked = NO;
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

}
```

`isChecked` is a BOOL that's declared in the header and `selectedItem.inCart` are my core data entity and boolean attribute, respectively.

EDIT: Here's the code in `ItemsVC` where the checkbox appears.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)IVCTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [IVCTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    Item *item = [fetchedResultsController_ objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withItem:item];

    UILabel *itemLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 40)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:itemLabel];
    itemLabel.text = item.itemName;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    Checkbox *checkbox = [[Checkbox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 50)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:checkbox];


    return cell;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's the current state of my code, with comments about what works and what doesn't. At this point, the checkbox will check and uncheck, but the check will repeat every 10 rows, which I assume is where `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is doing its thing.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
    // Initialization code

    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

// If I don't set these images here, they don't appear in the table 
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self addTarget:self action: @selector(checkboxTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
return self;
}

// This function prevents checked checkboxes from unchecking
/*
- (void)setIsChecked:(BOOL)isChecked {
if (isChecked == isChecked_)
    return;
[self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:isChecked_?@"checked.png":@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.selectedItem.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isChecked_];
}


*/
- (IBAction) checkboxTapped {
if (self.isChecked == NO) {
    self.isChecked = YES;
// If I comment this out, the checked.png doesn't render
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.selectedItem.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isChecked_];
    // I commented this out because for some reason it prevents the checkbox from unchecking
    //self.isChecked = [[selectedItem_ inCart] boolValue];
    } else {
    self.isChecked = NO;
// If I comment this out, once the checkbox is checked, it won't uncheck
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.selectedItem.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isChecked_];
    self.isChecked = [[selectedItem_ inCart] boolValue];
}

}
```

I left `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as @imaginaryboy suggested, except I used `checkBox.isChecked = [[item inCart] boolValue];` as @westsider suggested. While this seems cleaner than what I was doing before, I'm not quite sure how to handle my original issue. I've been re-reading the docs, yet remain at a loss. Is there a way to check that `inCart` is actually getting its state changed? As for the checked cells, should I be caching them, or writing cells to a plist, or giving each cell its own unique identifier at creation (as I'm writing this, that seems like the way to go. Yes?)?

It occurs to me that if I was really successful in changing the state of inCart (which is a core data attribute), shouldn't its state be saved automatically when the checkbox gets checked, assuming that `checkBox.isChecked = [[item inCart] boolValue];` works?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as I commented on a little while ago, you're reusing cells but adding a new `UILabel` and `Checkbox` every time a cell is reused in addition to when it's first created.

To sort that out, something like the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UILabel *itemLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 100, 40)];
        itemLabel.tag = 1;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:itemLabel];

        Checkbox *checkbox = [[Checkbox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 50)];
        checkbox.tag = 2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkbox];
    }

    Item *item = [fetchedResultsController_ objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell withItem:item];

    UILabel *itemLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    itemLabel.text = item.itemName;

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    Checkbox *checkbox = (Checkbox*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    checkbox.isChecked = YES or NO based on item.inCart??

    return cell;
}
```

Though actually rather than setting the itemLabel.text and checkbox state here, perhaps the method `configureCell:withItem:` that you're calling could/should do that?

With respect to the issue you're having where the state isn't preserved between navigations, it may be simply that you're adding this new `Checkbox` to the cell every time and so it's appearing in whatever it's default checked/unchecked state is.

Also, you may want to try something like the following in `Checkbox`:

```
- (void)setIsChecked:(BOOL)isChecked {
    if (isChecked_ = isChecked)
        return;
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:isChecked_?@"checked.png":@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.selectedItem.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isChecked_];
}


- (IBAction) checkboxTapped {
    if (self.isChecked == NO) {
        self.isChecked = YES;
    } else {
        self.isChecked = NO;
    }
}
```

EDIT: modified assigment of self.selectedItem.inCart as per @westsider's comment

Comment: OK, but I'm still getting the same error that I did before, where `self.selectedItem.inCart = isChecked_;` gives me the warning `Passing argument 1 of 'setInCart:' makes pointer from integer without a cast`. I can only assume that's where the problem in saving state is. `inCart` is set as a BOOL in my xcdatamodel, but is an NSNumber in `Item.h`. I used the core data defaults, but this might be where the problem is?

Comment: self.selectedItem.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isChecked_];

Comment: Edited the answer to deal with the `Passing argument 1 of ...` warning.

Comment: OK, this is weird. With the new `self.selectedItem.inCart` assignment, the check persists when I navigate to `ItemDetailVC`, but loses it if I navigate to the `RVC`. Also, I can't uncheck the box any more.

Comment: That seems to imply to me that the state of the checkbox state isn't correctly set when a cell is updated. Why? Navigating back to root destroys the table and cells so returning creates all new ones. Navigating down to details preserved the level above (as long as there are no memory warnings processed that cause the views to unload), so going back you're probably looking at the exact same cell instances.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need some code somewhere that actually sets the checkbox image based on the value of selectedItem.inCart. My guess is that inside ItemsVC you will want to implement -viewWillAppear: or -viewDidAppear: and iterate through your checkboxes, setting them as would be appropriate.

Without seeing more of your code, I can't suggest any more than this.

Comment: The checkbox is added in cellForRowAtIndexPath as a subview. The problem isn't that the proper image doesn't get called (it does), but that it doesn't persist if I navigate away. In other words, if I check the box, it gets checked, but if I go back to RVC, then back to that ItemsVC, the box is unchecked again.

Comment: Be that as it may, the issue remains that you are not retrieving 'inCart' anywhere - and that would seem to be the 'persisted' value that you are setting to store the state of the checkboxes. On top of that, I think that you should simply be changing state in -checkboxTapped: ... otherwise, why bother defining two states in -initFrame: ?

Comment: Also, it looks like are creating new Checkbox objects too often.

Comment: Yup, that is *exactly* the problem, the solution to which continues to elude me. :)

Comment: As for the -initWithFrame, if I don't define the states there, the images don't render in the cell, and if I don't call the images in - checkboxTapped, then they don't change state when the box is tapped. I thought I was calling one checkbox per cell. Is there a leak?

Comment: @Paul - There's not a leak, but you're creating a new UILabel and a new Checkbox every time the UITableView requests a cell.  Note that the UITableView doesn't request a cell for every row, it requests one for every VISIBLE row.  As you scroll the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will start returning cells which you've previously created and already added added a UILabel and Checkbox to.

Comment: As imaginaryboy pointed out, you need to *get* the value of inCart in order to take advantage of the persistence. You are setting inCart. Something like: checkbox.isChecked = [[item inCart] boolValue];